# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null Can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

Getting a console error as the title says on this portion of code:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    recognition.start();
});
```

This is the JS

```
    const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.txt-content');

// Custom response array for Greetings
const greetings = ['I\'m doing well, thanks', 'Doing good brother!', 'Please leave me alone, not in the mood brah'];

// Custom response array for Weather 
const weather = ['The weather is fine today', 'You need a tan good sir', 'It is going to rain cats and dogs'];

const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = function () {
    console.log('voice is activated, you can speak into your microphone');
};

recognition.onspeechend = function (event) {
    const current = event.resultIndex;
    const transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
    content.textContent = transcript;
    readOutLoud(transcript);
};

// Add the listener to the button
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    recognition.start();
});

function readOutLoud(message) {
    const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

    speech.text = 'i dont know what you said';

    // if statement for custom response array
    if (message.includes('how are you')) {
        const finalText = greetings[Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length)];
        speech.text = finalText;
    }

    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;

    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

Comment: Because `btn` is null. We will have no idea why unless you show us how your are acquiring `btn` in the first place (JavaScript and HTML).

Answer (score -2):

This is because, `btn` is pointing to `null`. Please check, what do you get when your console `btn`.